# Error installing fakeXrandr library - Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, compiling, xrandr, arm

I have successfully installed a ubuntu image on my Raspberry Pi 4. I am trying to do some screen customization, and so as a result I'm looking to install this project, fakeXrandr:

https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr

Following their install steps, after installing some dependencies, I get the following error which seems related to my architecture (i.e. the RPi):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/fakexrandr-master$ sudo make
./configure
XRandR version is 1.5.2
The path to the real XRandR library is /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXrandr.so.2

ERROR: Failed to find a suitable directory for the fakeXrandr library

You must place the library into the library search path, in a directory preceeding
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf. In your system, this leaves the following candidates:

None of these contains `local', therefore I won't autoconfigure the installation to one
of these directories. Either add a high-priority directory in /usr/local using the ldconfig
mechanism (See /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ on most systems) or manually create config.h.

make: *** [Makefile:7: config.h] Error 1
```

Any ideas how I can overcome this?

(As an alternative, if for whatever reason this library won't work on my setup, what I'm really trying to do is set up virtual monitors so I can cut my screen in half and dual-mirror it. So I'd gladly look into anything else that could help me with this.)

Thanks.

Comment: Read `man ld.so`. Create a directory with "`local`" in its name (e.g. `/usr/local/lib/fakexrandr`). Read `man ld.so.conf` and insert the newly created directory before `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`. Read `man ldconfig`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll look into it :) Care to add an answer?